# Openlayers stylemap label not working wfs

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, vector, wfs, style

I have created a style map like following:

```
    var scadaPointStyle = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
        "default": new OpenLayers.Style("null", {
            "rules": [
                new OpenLayers.Rule({
                    "symbolizer": {
                        "Point": {
                            pointRadius: 15,
                            fillColor: "#3DCDE0",
                            fillOpacity: 0.9,
                            strokeColor: "white",
                            label: "${point_id}",
                            fontColor: "white",
                            cursor: "pointer"
                        }
                    }
                })
            ]
        }),
        "select": new OpenLayers.Style("null", {
            "rules": [
                new OpenLayers.Rule({
                    "symbolizer": {
                        "Point": {
                            pointRadius: 15,
                            fillColor: "#323D34",
                            fillOpacity: 0.9,
                            strokeColor: "white",
                            label: "${point_id}",
                            fontColor: "white",
                            cursor: "pointer"
                        }
                    }
                })
            ]
        })
});
```

And my vector layer is like this:

```
    var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(null, {
            "protocol": new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                featureType: featureType,
                version: "1.1.0",
                url: myurl,
                featurePrefix: myeaturePrefix,
                geometryName: myGeometryName,
                srsName: mysrs,
                isBaseLayer: false
            }),
            "styleMap": scadaPointStyle,
            "strategies": [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster()],
            "eventListeners": {
                "featureselected": onSelected,
                "featureunselected": onUnselected,
                "loadstart": onLoadStarted,
                "loadend": onLoadEnd
            }
    });
```

Point style is working and appearing on map. But label text is **undefined**.

I added contecxt to style like this:

```
context:function(feature){
       return faeture.attributes.point_id;
}
```

but didn't worked.

May be about cluster strategy?

I removed cluster strategy but this time pint style didn't appear.

Answer (score 1):

At OpenLayers Cookbook code examples (http://acanimal.github.io/Openlayers-Cookbook/) there is a working example, see "Chapter7 - Styling - Improving style using StyleMap and feature's attributes replacement".

Create your style intent without using rules, really you are not using them because you are not setting any condition to filter. For example try creating the `default` style as:

```
var style = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]);
style.pointRadius = "${radius}";
style.fillColor = '${colorFunction}';
```